# How can I extend the Tab key auto-completion in the terminal to text in the middle of a command?

Tags: command-line, bash

Example file: `Selection_192.png`

1. `$ ls 192`
2. Now I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice
3. It should auto-complete to `$ ls Selection_192.png`

**Note:**

It should not only work with `ls` but any kind of command and be preferably a solution that works with the default shell in Ubuntu Unity 16.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't mention the specific shell, one way is to install `zsh`.

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
# now change the default shell
chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

Now as you got zsh as the default shell instead of bash, [to get a fuzzy completion add this to `~/.zshrc`](https://superuser.com/a/815317/304864) file:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' \
  'm:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}' \
  'r:[^[:alpha:]]||[[:alpha:]]=** r:|=* m:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}' \
  'r:|?=** m:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}'
```

For example, this is how my `~/.zshrc` looks like:

```
 # bash style (read as the adequate) for navigating words
 autoload -U select-word-style
 select-word-style bash

 # some plugins
 source /usr/share/zsh/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
 source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
 ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_HIGHLIGHT_STYLE='fg=7'
 zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' \
         'm:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}' \
         'r:[^[:alpha:]]||[[:alpha:]]=** r:|=* m:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}' \
         'r:|?=** m:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}'
 bindkey \^U backward-kill-line

 #useful aliases
 alias grep1="grep --exclude-dir=\".*\""
 alias gdb="gdb -q"
```

**NB**: usefulness of zsh is that it is very extensible, and in many ways compatible to bash. On the opposite, e.g. fish *(another alternative to bash, which is pretty much like a configured zsh)* in my experience causes many incompatibility problems.

**UPD**: per OP comments: if you want to raise the requirement for letters to be close to each another *(i.e. instead of fuzzy completion it's just a subsequence completion)*, then *instead* of regexp I mentioned [you can put to `~/.zshrc` this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22627273/2388257):

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{[:lower:][:upper:]}={[:upper:][:lower:]}' '+l:|=* r:|=*'
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! Preferably I would use a solution that works with the default shell of Ubuntu 16.04. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @orschiro the default shell in Ubuntu 16.04 is `bash` you might probably want to also add the tag `bash`.

Comment: @orschiro also for bash you're probably [could try that](http://superuser.com/a/607338/304864).

Comment: I tried to use your solution but it does not work. May you advise me based on [this](http://imgur.com/a/CGtit) GIF animation what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @orschiro it's that you have more than one file in the directory with the `1`,`9`,`2` letters in this order. Fuzzy completion looses requirements by not mandating for the letters to be close each to another. I wrote in the update how to raise this requirement.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)! I finally installed and used this one as follows. First, I type `up`, followed by `Ctrl+t`. This opens a list of files. Here I can search for `192` and press enter. The path is being inserted after the `up`.